# Linux rename command pattern

Tags: linux

I have folder with 400 images. And all titles is something like `modarticle_52a23d7220e63_logo-min.jpg` my goal is using linux command `rename` rename all files removing part `-min` from titles. What pattern I should use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With rename:

```
rename s/-min// *
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
rename -- "-min" "" *.jpg
```

You need `--`, otherwise `rename` would think `-m` is an unknown option
and fail.